# Partial Sums from a Given Column

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if there is a quick way to have Excel sum up chunks of a selected column based on where blanks appear in that column.  For example, the column might look like:

```
10
12
15
11

2
3
10
13
14

14
13

1
9
8
6
```

and ideally each partial total would be placed where the first element being summed was previously.  Can this be done without VBA?

Comment: Do you want the sum next to the blank between **11** & **2** ??

Comment: @Gary That would work, or beside the first number of each sub-group.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Leave **B1** empty, In **B2** enter:

```
=IF(A2<>"","",SUM($A$1:A2)-SUM($B$1:B1))
```

and copy down............should look like:

[image: Result]